# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: java, mysql

Por alguna razón en la última actualización de windows el servidor apache dejó de funcionar, y a pesar de haber probado todas las soluciones posibles no logre solucionarlo, decidí instalar wamp, que contiene la versión 8.0 de MySQL, pero a correr el programa en la conexión me arroja el error utilizando el `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.driver`, volví a instalar la librería de la versión 5.1, y sigue arrojando el mismo error, cual es la solución al problema?, adjunto el código de conexión

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.*;
 
public class MySqlConexion {
    
  public static final String ConsLogin="com.mysql.jdbc.driver";

  public static Connection getConexion(){
    
    Connection Conectado = null;
    
    try{
        Class.forName(ConsLogin);
        Conectado=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/volverhacer","root","");
        System.out.println("conectado correctamente!");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        System.out.println("DESCONECTADO! " + e);
    }
    
    return Conectado;
  }
}
```

Comment: No se si sea el caso pero creo que driver deberia de comenzar con mayuscula: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 2):

Lo que ocurre es que **no has incluido la biblioteca de conectividad a mysql** en tu proyecto.

Para resolverlo, sigue una de estas recomendaciones:

- **Proyectos maven**

Agrega la dependencia al *mysql-connector* en tu archivo `pom.xml`, por ejemplo:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Encontrarás todas las versiones del conector en: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

- **En cualquier proyecto**

  Agrega manualmente la biblioteca `jar` al proyecto.

  - Haz clic con el botón derecho del *mouse* en tu proyecto -- > *build path* -- > *configure build path*
  - En la pestaña `Libraries` presiona `Add External jar` y selecciona el `jar` que contiene el conector.

    Encontrarás un zip con el *mysql-connector* [aquí](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html)
- ***Explicación:***

  Java lanza la excepción porque dentro del proyecto no se ha registrado la clase del conector `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, que se encuentra en la biblioteca de conectividad a *mysql*. Los pasos descritos arriba darán como resultado el registro de dicha clase en tu proyecto.

Comment: O si estás usando Java _a pie_, sería incluir el jar del driver JDBC de MySQL en el classpath.... con la opción `-cp`.

Comment: estoy utilizando Java con NetBeans, es la primera vez que lo uso, el proyecto funcionaba perfecto hasta que surgió este problema, no encuentro el archivo pom.xml que mencionas en la respuesta

Comment: ¿qué tipo de proyecto es? Si no es maven, no existe ese archivo.

Comment: Es una pagina JSP, con un Servlet y una clase de acceso a datos, ya lo solucione, era un problema, tan tonto, que no pude encontrarlo a simple vista, al asignar el valor "com.mysql.jdbc.driver", no me di cuenta que driver va con mayúsculas

Answer (score 1):

A simple vista Un problema posible es que estas llamando a la clase:  com.mysql.jdbc.driver y debe ser com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -> D con mayuscula.

```
public static final String ConsLogin="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/volverhacer?user=root&password=pass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Posible fallo :

```
 private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/volverhacer?serverTimezone=UTC";
```

ponle detrás el ?serverTimezone=UTC debido que se puede haber cambiado la zona horaria

```
/*Si no ponemos lo de serverTimezone habría que cambiar en el servidor mysql la variable global
time_zone −> show global variables like ’time_zone’; o select @@global.time_zone;
devuelve SYSTEM y debería coger la configuración válida de nuestra zona
 horaria del sistema operativo, pero no lo hace bien, podemos ponerla a mano con 
SET GLOBAL time_zone = ’+1:00’;
pero hemos de tener en cuenta los cambios horarios de verano/invierno
lo mejor es dejar a mysql como está y añadir al URL de la base de datos ?serverTimezone=UTC 
(que debería encajar con lo que haya en nuestro sistema)
```